# How to stop annoying systemd log message: Starting Poll for Ubuntu Pro licenses

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

How to stop this annoying message?

```
Nov 23 08:44:48 hostname systemd[1]: Started Poll for Ubuntu Pro licenses (Only enabled on GCP LTS non-pro).
Nov 23 08:47:48 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Poll for Ubuntu Pro licenses (Only enabled on GCP LTS non-pro)..
```

On `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`

systemd current version is: `systemd-237-3ubuntu10.52`

Answer (score 2):

This log come from cron task of `ubuntu-advantage-tools` see [Ubuntu Advantage](https://ubuntu.com/advantage).

Just remove the package:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-advantage-tools
```